# How to identify types which is passed as dynamic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf-4.0

i have two wpf pages - Master page and Group page, group page is passing the Entity to Master page constructors, am using dynamic keyword to pass entity, each time a different entity is passing to master page, how can i identify that what entity have been passed to Master page...

```
Class Master
 {

  Public Master (window parent, dynamic element)
  {
    ...
  }
 }

Class Group
{
  public void sendtomaster()
  {
    Master objMaster = new Master(window parentItem, dynamic entityItem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GetType like any other object.

```
    dynamic d = 1; 
    Type t = d.GetType();
```

t would be System.Int32